# Identical Dockerfile builds on macOS Docker but NOT on Raspbian (Stretch) Docker

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, dockerfile

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update && apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:mrazavi/gvm && apt install gvm -y
```

When building with Docker in Raspbian the following error occurs:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package gvm
The command '/bin/sh -c add-apt-repository ppa:mrazavi/gvm && apt install gvm -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Build command:

```
docker build --no-cache -t openvas .
```

**On macOS the build is always okay.**

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because the images or the packages you are trying to use are not cross-platform compiled.

You need to review your dependencies or try a different FROM image to test with a different architecture.